# Duplicate subdomain mapping on Google App Engine with www prefix

Tags: google-app-engine, subdomain

Some of my clients are having problems accessing my Google App Engine website from typing in the URL. Despite it being written down - it's on a printed invite - as http://subdomain.domain.com (which works), people insist on putting in http://www.subdomain.domain.com

Is there some way of adding another mapping to make www.subdomain.domain.com point at subdomain.domain.com??

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply add that subdomain in Google Apps (following the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html)). Failing that, you could use a third-party redirection service to send a 302 to your 'real' subdomain.